# Why would ch341-uart be disconnected from ttyUSB?

Tags: embedded, stm32

I want to flash my STM32 board with my USB serial port. And my STM32 board comes with an extended board which carries CH340.

When I connected the board to my computer, I can see the device with the command [`lsusb`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lspci#lsusb), and the output is `Bus 001 Device 039: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics CH340 serial converter`.

But I can't find the `ttyUSB` file under `/dev` path.

I ran `dmesg | grep tty`, and here is the output:

```
[1182096.667353] usb 1-9: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[1182096.729868] audit: type=1130 audit(1637925474.011:3648): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=brltty-device@sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d9 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[1182096.800144] audit: type=1130 audit(1637925474.081:3649): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=brltty@-sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d9 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[1182096.803145] usb 1-9: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by ch341 while 'brltty' sets config #1
[1182096.803731] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Unable to use USB dongle based on USB-serial converter chip](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/670636/unable-to-use-usb-dongle-based-on-usb-serial-converter-chip)

Answer (score 96):

For [Ubuntu 22.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_22.04_LTS_(Jammy_Jellyfish)) (Jammy Jellyfish), the simplest solution is to remove the package brltty via `sudo apt remove brltty`, since it’s unnecessary unless you're using a [braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille) e-reader. However, I am unsure if it could cause errors later on.

Also for information about brltty, visit [their site](https://brltty.app/).

Comment: perfect did work for me with Ubuntu 22.04. Thanks a lot

Comment: How awful to ship a distro with built-in software that's hard coded exclusively to claim ttyUSB0 and disconnect when hardware is not known by the software

Comment: the question is: why was this installed in 22.04?

Comment: My friend have similar problem, but log is slightly different:
'sudo dmesg | grep ttyUSB
[   27.433315] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: break control not supported, using simulated break
[   27.433369] usb 1-8: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[   28.079264] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0...'
Your answer - helped, thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

There is the forum post *[Can't connect serial port - Error: ch341-uart disconnected from ttyUSB0](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/cant-connect-serial-port-error-ch341-uart-disconnected-from-ttyusb0/87208)*. It seems for an [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux)/[Manjaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manjaro) system (I am not sure if it is suitable for other distribution), you need to remove some [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) rules.

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-brltty-device.rules /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-brltty-device.rules.disabled
sudo mv /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-brltty-uinput.rules /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-brltty-uinput.rules.disabled
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

I don't know why, but I did it. And it worked. Now I can find my `ttyUSB0` device file.

Comment: Worked for me on EndeavourOS with kernel 5.17.2-arch3-1.

Comment: Maybe it is because of the same reason on ubuntu: The software `brltty` "seizes" the device.

Answer (score 8):

So, there is a braille ereader that uses this same serial converter, and the udev rules configure the chip for that device. You actually don't need to remove the udev rules files completely, you can simply disable/comment out the rule for the single device. It is this one:

```
# Device: 1A86:7523
# Baum [NLS eReader Zoomax (20 cells)]
ENV{PRODUCT}=="1a86/7523/*", ENV{BRLTTY_BRAILLE_DRIVER}="bm", GOTO="brltty_usb_run"
```

Comment the line starting with ENV.

Comment: Good answer that explains the reason. Actually saw that "braille" in syslog but did not think it was important. But it a was.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to see the device using [lsusb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lspci#lsusb) and [dmesg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmesg)/[grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) tty, but I was not able to upload code from [PlatformIO](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlatformIO).

```
sudo apt remove brltty
```

This fixed my upload issue with [ESP8266](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP8266) (CH341-UART converter) on [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa).